# Partial specialization of class template with minimal code duplication

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, optional, duplicate-code

I have a class template that stores an `std::optional<T>`. A very reduced version of the class template looks like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class param {
public:
    param() = default;
    param(T const& t) : m_value(t) {}

    bool is_valid() const { return m_value.has_value(); }

    T const& value() const
    {
        if (!is_valid()) {
            /* snip */
            assert(is_valid());
        }

        return m_value.value();
    }
private:
    std::optional<T> m_value;
};
```

Note that the class is meant for lazy evaluation and caching, so in the line containing the comment `/* snip */` I omitted a bunch of code irrevelevant to my question. The point of the `optional` is that a param instance can be in a valid or invalid state and the valid state can be triggered via evaluation.

Now I want the class template to work also with references. This is useful for instance if I want to lazily access a class member.

Since `std::optional` does not allow the usage of references, I believe I need a partial specialization of `param` for `T&`. The partial specialization must store an `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>`. But this leads to a lot of code duplicaton, since I really only need to modify the constructor, one line in `value` and the member definition. Note that here I am showing just a minimal example. In production code, `param` has much more code, but even there I only need to modify a small percentage of the code in the partial specialization.

```cpp
template <typename T>
class param<T&> 
{
public:
    param() = default;
    param(T& t) : m_value(std::ref(t)) {}

    bool is_valid() const { return m_value.has_value(); }

    T const& value() const
    {
        if (!is_valid()) {
            /* snip */
            assert(is_valid());
        }

        return m_value.value().get();
    }
private:
    std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>> m_value;
};
```

[Live Code](https://godbolt.org/z/jsMMMK1vs)

One way to avoid this unnecessary duplication of code is to use inheritence:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class param<T&> : public param<std::reference_wrapper<T>>
{
    using Base = param<std::reference_wrapper<T>>;
public:
    param(T& t) : Base(std::ref(t)) {}

    T const& value() const {
        return Base::value().get();
    }
};
```

I explicitly did not add a virtual destructor to `param<T>`, because I want to avoid vtable lookups. I don't intent to ever use the specialization polymorphically. That being said, the class template is in the public API of the library and experience says that if you give a user the possiblity of doing something wrong, some user will eventually do something wrong. In addition, what happens if I add protected members to the unspecialized class template?

So my questions regarding the above code are

1. Are there any other (better?) approaches to supporting references *and* avoiding code duplication?
2. Are there any pros and cons of the two approaches I listed that I have missed? Which way should I go?

### Addendum:

Here is yet another option using `if constexpr` and `std::conditional` that does not require specialization at all. But IMHO overall the readibility suffers.

```cpp
template <typename T>
class param {
public:
    param() = default;

    param(T const& t) : m_value(
        [&](){
            if constexpr (std::is_reference_v<T>){
                return std::ref(t);
            }
            else {
                return t;
            }
        }()
    ) {}

    bool is_valid() const { return m_value.has_value(); }

    T const& value() const
    {
        if (!is_valid()) {
            /* snip */
            assert(is_valid());
        }

        if constexpr (std::is_reference_v<T>) {
            return m_value.value().get();
        } else {
            return m_value.value();
        }
    }
private:
    using CacheType = std::conditional_t<
        !std::is_reference_v<T>, 
        std::optional<T>,
        std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>
    >;
    CacheType m_value;
};
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/8canqKMG8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid inheritance and go for the implementation in the addendum. However, you can significantly simplify it:

- It's fine to unconditionally use `std::ref()` in the constructor. If `T` is not a reference, then temporarily making a `std::reference_wrapper` for it will not change how `m_value` is initialized.
- Similarly, you can unconditionally return `m_value.value()` in `value()`, since if it was a `std::reference_wrapper`, it will invoke the implicit `operator T&()` that is equivalent to calling `.get()`.
- You can hoist `std::optional` out of `CacheType`.

In summary, you can rewrite your code as:

```
template <typename T>
class param {
public:
    param() = default;
    param(T const& t) : m_value(std::ref(t)) {}

    bool is_valid() const { return m_value.has_value(); }

    T const& value() const
    {
        if (!is_valid()) {
            /* snip */
            assert(is_valid());
        }

        return m_value.value();        
    }
private:
    using ValueType = std::conditional_t<
        !std::is_reference_v<T>, 
        T,
        std::reference_wrapper<std::remove_reference<T>>
    >;
    std::optional<ValueType> m_value;
};
```

The `using` statement is now the only extra line you had to write to support both values and references.

Comment: I stumbled on an issue with the implicit conversions from `reference_wrapper<T> to `T` in the constructor of `param<T>`: If `T` is not a reference and has a greedy constructor, it will take precedence over the conversion operator of `reference_wrapper`:  https://godbolt.org/z/oh4xGrErb